# How to retrieve GET vars in python bottle app

Tags: python, bottle, query-string

I'm trying to make a simple REST api using the Python bottle app.
I'm facing a problem in retrieving the GET variables from the request global object.
Any suggestions how to retrieve this from the GET request?

Answer (score 35):

They are stored in the `request.query` object.

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#query-variables

It looks like you can also access them by treating the `request.query` attribute like a dictionary:

```
request.query['city']
```

So `dict(request.query)` would create a dictionary of all the query parameters.

As @mklauber notes, this will not work for multi-byte characters. It looks like the best method is:

```
my_dict = request.query.decode()
```

or:

```
dict(request.query.decode())
```

to have a `dict` instead of a `<bottle.FormsDict object at 0x000000000391B...>` object.

Comment: Note, based on the docs, dict based access does not properly decode and renecode multi-byte characters.

Comment: Ah, yeah it seems like `my_dict = request.query.decode()` is correct way.

Answer (score 6):

If you want them all:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

dict = parse_qs(request.query_string)
```

If you want one:

```
one = request.GET.get('one', '').strip()
```

Comment: or you could just use `request.query.one`

Comment: @f p: it returns an empty string as well as your code. The only difference is that request.query.one is always a Unicode string.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this please:

For this example : http://localhost:8080/command?param_name=param_value

In your code:

```
param_value = request.query.param_name
```

Answer (score 0):

from the docs

```
name = request.cookies.name
# is a shortcut for:
name = request.cookies.getunicode('name') # encoding='utf-8' (default)
# which basically does this:
try:
    name = request.cookies.get('name', '').decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeError:
    name = u''
```

So you might prefer using attribute accessor (request.query.variable_name) than request.query.get('variable_name')

Another point is you can use request.params.variable_name which works both for GET and POST methods, than having to swich request.query.variable_name or request.forms.variable_name depending GET/POST.